# Disabling Traffic Control in Linux

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, qos

I have read that Traffic Control feature in Linux will try to shape the egress traffic to remove bursts and has its own queue mechanism.

I am trying to generate traffic at higher rates as a result Traffic Control would be a bottle neck in my case.

How could I disable it so that there is no queuing done by traffic control in linux ?

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK this could be done only while compiling kernel:

> Many distributions provide kernels with modular or monolithic support
>   for traffic control (Quality of Service). Custom kernels may not
>   already provide support (modular or not) for the required features.

Example 1. Kernel compilation options

```
CONFIG_NET_SCHED=y
CONFIG_NET_SCH_CBQ=m
CONFIG_NET_SCH_HTB=m
CONFIG_NET_SCH_CSZ=m
CONFIG_NET_SCH_PRIO=m
CONFIG_NET_SCH_RED=m
CONFIG_NET_SCH_SFQ=m
CONFIG_NET_SCH_TEQL=m
CONFIG_NET_SCH_TBF=m
CONFIG_NET_SCH_GRED=m
CONFIG_NET_SCH_DSMARK=m
CONFIG_NET_SCH_INGRESS=m
CONFIG_NET_QOS=y
CONFIG_NET_ESTIMATOR=y
CONFIG_NET_CLS=y
CONFIG_NET_CLS_TCINDEX=m
CONFIG_NET_CLS_ROUTE4=m
CONFIG_NET_CLS_ROUTE=y
CONFIG_NET_CLS_FW=m
CONFIG_NET_CLS_U32=m
CONFIG_NET_CLS_RSVP=m
CONFIG_NET_CLS_RSVP6=m
CONFIG_NET_CLS_POLICE=y
```

Please refer to [this](http://linux-ip.net/articles/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/) document for more details.

Also remember that besides Traffic Control there are many other mechanisms that are limiting traffic and actually allows network to work properly (like TCP congestion control for example).

Comment: but in my case I am creating udp pkt in my linux module and transmitting it. So ideally TCP congestion would never be an issue

Comment: If so you don't have to worry about TCP congestion control mechanisms. Anyway you can read document I have linked and try to recompile kernel to disable all possible traffic control issues.

Comment: I am on my way trying it :) thanx. But if there is an easier way to disable it other than kernel option would be great